# What is the motivation behind the obligated number of times different workers are required to fulfill their conjugal rights obligations?

Tags: time, sexuality

In Hilchot Ishut the Rambam gives different requirements to men to fulfill their conjugal rights obligations (http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952888/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Fourteen.htm).

Paraphrased:

- Healthy men who are pampered and indulged - every night
- a talmid chacham - once a week
- a worker - twice a weak
- a seaman - once every six months

The shulchan aruch gives the same halachah.

What is the motivation behind these numbers? Is this the lower limit, the upper limit? If marital relations is a holy act, why should it be limited? If marital relations is negative, why should the pampered and indulged men have it every night?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64557/759

Answer (score 5):

The periodicity of visits of the husband at home and his work*, and how mach he remains valid and strong after hardness of labor and business(Source Mishna Keubot [5, 6](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01302.html#HtmpReportNum0046_L2), difference between "walkers" and "workers", see also Gemara Ketubot [62a](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=62&format=pdf), the words of SA EH [76,1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7713) are according to his strength and his work). When a woman will marry a seaman, she doesn't protest against the fact that doesn't come up often enough. So she cannot require "Ona" more frequently.

If a woman is already married to a worker, and he decide to be a seaman, she can prevent it following the halacha and claim what is rightly her SA [EH 76, 5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7715). The only allowance to force the woman to accept is when he want to go away to Yeshiva.

The number is a minimal requirement, i.e. a maximal interval between onot

---

See SA [EH 76](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7713)

---

Thank you to @Shalom for remember me the work criterion and lower number.